# Ruby Hash & Array to xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, api, hash, xml-serialization

I'm using ActiveSupport's to_xml to generate some xml from a hash.

I have need for the this ruby:

```
:Shipment => {
  :Packages => [
    {:weight => '5', :type => 'box'},
    {:weight => '3', :type => 'tube'}
  ]
}
```

To generate this xml:

```
<Shipment>
  <Package>
    <weight>5</weight>
    <type>box</type>
  </Package>
  <Package>
    <weight>3</weight>
    <type>tube</type>
  </Package>
</Shipment>
```

But instead, it wraps the array in another set of xml tags like this:

```
<Shipment>
  <Packages>
    <Package>
      <weight>5</weight>
      <type>box</type>
    </Package>
    <Package>
      <weight>3</weight>
      <type>tube</type>
    </Package>
  </Packages>
</Shipment>
```

Please don't tell me I need to change my xml structure... It's how UPS says to do it :(

Anybody know a work-around?

Comment: I was just checking out Builder...looks pretty cool. Any recommendations to other ruby xml tools would be great. I already checked out xml-simple...it seems a little limited. REXML seems like it may be complicated to just change a hash to xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking out builder is the way to go. Your xml.builder will look something like:

```
xml.shipment do
    @packages.each do |package|
        xml.package do
            xml.weight package.weight
            xml.type package.type
        end
    end
end
```